# Aura:if not working as expected?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-if

I am trying to display the price of the item if the price is not equal to 0. Whats would be wrong with the usage below? The '0' here is a currency data type in the custom object. Please advise!

```
 <li><strong>{! ch.Name}</strong><span>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!equals(ch.sumchans__StandalonePrice__c, 0)}">
       (${! ch.sumchans__StandalonePrice__c})
    </aura:if>
   </span>
 </li>
```

Thanks All!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `{!` pair starts the expression (and `}` terminates the expression) rather than the `!` character negating the expression.

So use e.g.:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{! notequals(ch.sumchans__StandalonePrice__c, 0) }">
```

or:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{! !equals(ch.sumchans__StandalonePrice__c, 0) }">
```

Comment: +1 but I'm not sure I'd use the term "deliminter", since that might lead to some confusion (a delimiter can appear "between" values, but this only appears at the beginning). It's more fair to say that "`{!` starts an expression and is not part of the expression that is evaluated." or something like that.

Comment: @sfdcfox Goog point, I've changed it.